# Does webpack remove custom variables or event listeners attached to `window` in production?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

### The problem:

We're facing an issue where any event listeners or global variables we attach to `window` does not seem to be there in our `production` build (but they are there in the `development` build).

- Webpack config: https://gist.github.com/saadq/9f2f800c88716d11410e63859382f47d
- Build script: `webpack --mode=production`

---

**Context**:

We have a use case where our webapp renders inside a parent app. The parent app basically needs to tell us when we need to render our app. To do this, we have tried using event listeners as well as global functions.

### How our app is loaded into the parent app

To render our webapp inside the parent app, the following happens:

1. The parent app makes an HTTP call to `myappwebsite.com/asset-manifest.json`. This is like the default `asset-manifest.json` that gets created for any `create-react-app` webapp.
2. The parent app finds the path to the main `bundle.js` from this asset manifest, and then makes an HTTP call to fetch our `bundle.js` using this path (e.g. `myappwebsite.com/bundle.js`).
3. They dynamically inject a `script` tag into their `head` with its `src` set to our `bundle.js` to load our app's bundled javascript.
4. They listen for the `onload` event of this new `script` element before trying to call any of our code or dispatching any events.

### Attempt 1

**Child app:**

```
// index.tsx

window.addEventListener('renderApp', (event) => {
  console.log('This is running!'); // This only prints in `development`
  const { rootId } = event.detail;
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById(rootId));
})
```

**Parent app:**

```
// index.tsx

console.log('Dispatch is running!'); // This prints in both `development` and `production`
const renderEvent = new CustomEvent('renderApp', { detail: rootId: 'root' });

// This runs in the script.onload function to wait for our app to load
window.dispatchEvent(renderEvent);
```

This code works in the `development` build but not in the `production` build. In `production`, the dispatch does execute, but for some reason the event listener does not. When we tried to set some breakpoints on the minified production bundle, we noticed that the `addEventListener` code is there, however it is not actually executing... This is strange because the `addEventListener` is at the top level of the `index.tsx` in the child app and is not conditionally added.

---

### Attempt 2

**Child app:**

```
// index.tsx

window.renderApp = (rootId) => {
  console.log('Child render is running'); // This only prints in `development`
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById(rootId));
})
```

**Parent app:**

```
// index.tsx

console.log('Render is running!'); // This prints in both `development` and `production`

// This runs in the script.onload function to wait for our app to load
window.renderApp(rootId);
```

Same issue here, the code works in the `development` build but not in the `production` build. In `production`, the call goes through but the global function does not seem to be on `window`. I am able to verify this by printing out `window` in the console.

---

It seems that any globals I set on `window` or any event listeners I set to it get ignored in the production build. Is this by Webpack's design? Or do you think something is messed up in my config/build script that is causing this to happen?

Comment: > the global function does not seem to be on window <

then this line should cause an error in production:
`window.renderApp(rootId);`

do you see console error?

Comment: @Saad have you checked for `cors` issue and there is no other application which register same name function to window

Comment: @glinda93 Yeah, when I said "the global function does not seem to be on window" I meant that it is literally not on `window` and it causes an error. So it is confirmed that the function is not on `window`.

@Chandan The function does not exist at all on `window`, there is no conflict.

Comment: `renderApp` is defined in Child component. It maybe called in parent before definition? Somehow it works in dev but in production definition order matters...

Comment: This sounds more like a race condition issue more than a webpack issue. Both solutions should work in theory. Are you sure the parent calls the renderApp function/event after this is actually initialised?

Comment: Minimal reproducible example would be nice.

Comment: We are setting a bunch of things on `window` and this problem never occured for us. Could you `console.log` in the line before you are registering `window.renderApp` and in the line before you are calling it? I'm thinking a race condition like @Phil suggested is the most likely cause.

Comment: Can you try setting `target: "node"` instead of `target:"web"`?

Comment: Minimal repro may be hard since there are a lot of individual pieces that may be causing this issue. 

I'll be updating the question with more context with our script is loaded, hopefully that clarifies some stuff up.

Comment: Hi @glinda93, @Phil, @Taxel, and others, I've added a "How our app is loaded into the parent app" section above. This contains some pretty important context, sorry for not including it in the original post. I am wondering if dynamically loading our script tag is the issue with `window` not getting populated correctly. It's still weird that the issue doesn't happen in the `development` bundle though.

Comment: @Saad Is child component rendered inside an iframe?

Comment: No, the parent app has an empty div element in their HTML with an `id` of `rootId` which is what gets passed to the child app. It is used successfully in beta only...

Comment: According to your question, you should be having 2 entry points in the webpack one for parent another for the child...
However, your webpack config `entry: './src/index',` seems to have a single entry point.

Am I on the same page? Am I missing something?

Where are you importing index.js for child?

Comment: I've created minimal reproduceable example for your case https://github.com/stackoverflow-answers/q-69126274. it renders child element in dev & build that clarifies custom global variables are available in build.

Comment: @Saad in child app add logging before after event listener. that will help to figure out if event was actually registered before event was triggered from parent.

Comment: you could try removing the conditional configs 1 by 1 in your webpack file to see which is causing the issue in prod

Comment: @Saad Can you share the production url?

Comment: Is it possible your webpack dev build to be 1 file and prod 2 or more? Maybe order of execution is being mangled for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being an issue where the output of our bundle was separated into `main.js` and `vendor.js`, but we were only loading the `main.js` into the parent app.

Answer (score 0):

Add a node entry with `global: true` to your config:

```js
node: {
    global: true,
    __filename: false,
    __dirname: false,
  },
```

Comment: Doesn't this just create some Node polyfills? https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/#nodeglobal

Comment: Yes, but this trick once solved a similar issue than yours in my project. Sorry if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack does behave a bit strange when it comes to windows object and we can site number of discussions on this matter.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58718315/9640177) adding `globalObject: 'this'` line to the `output` section in webpack config file might fix the issue.

Other references
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7112
https://github.com/markdalgleish/static-site-generator-webpack-plugin/issues/130